# Show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\: |\: p\text{ prime})$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

I tried to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\: |\: p\text{ prime})$ is a normal extension of
$\mathbb{Q}$.

For finite extension we have that normal Extensions are splitting fields and vice versa,
but how can I argue in the case of an infinite extension ?

Is there an argument that the infinite union of normal extensions is normal (If yes, how can I proof that?) or is there a simple argument for that example?

Answer (score 5):

Any $\Bbb{Q}$-algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\: |\: p\text{ prime})$ to its algebraic closure sends $\sqrt{p}$ to $\pm\sqrt{p}$, whence it sends $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p}\: |\: p\text{ prime})$ to itself which is normal over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Equivalently it is the splitting field of an infinite set of polynomials $x^2-p\ | \ p$ prime.

Comment: When I was teaching Galois Theory, I pointed out that any compositum of normal extensions is normal, even if there are infinitely many.