Normal extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ inside of $\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, w)}$
Well, I guess there are a lot of answers about it, but I'd like to kindly ask you to explain what I understand wrong.
Def of normal extension that I use: field extension $F \subset L$ is called normal iff $\forall \alpha \in L$ all conjugates of $\alpha$ belong to $L$ too.
Let's look at $\mathbb{Q}$ and the following extensions: $Q(w), Q(\sqrt[3]{2}), Q(\sqrt[3]{2}w), Q(\sqrt[3]{2}w^2)$. I want to understand which extensions are normal.
We know that $\forall g \in Aut_{\mathbb{Q}}{\mathbb{Q(\sqrt[3]{2} \omega)}}$ maps conjugate to a conjugate. I think that $w$ can be mapped to $w$ or $w^2$ (why it can't be mapped to root ot 2?) and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ can be mapped to $\sqrt[3]{2}, w, w^2$.
Using this fact, we can conclude that $\mathbb{Q}(w)$ is normal extension. (if we show that $w$ can not be mapped to $\sqrt[3]{2}$). I understand why $\mathbb{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ is not normal: that's because $w$ does not belong to it. But why are $Q(\sqrt[3]{2}w), Q(\sqrt[3]{2}w^2)$ not normal? It seems like we can obtain all three: $\sqrt[3]{2}, w, w^2$ there. Pls help me get through it!

I presume by $\omega$ you mean a complex cube root of unity; perhaps you should state that explicitly.  Anyway, mapping $\sqrt[3]2$ to $\omega$ is not an automorphism, because $\sqrt[3]2^3=2$ but $\omega^3=1$

Neither $\omega$ nor $\root3\of2$ is an element of ${\bf Q}(\omega\root3\of2)$.

Quadratic extensions are normal, so $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ is normal.

What about all the answers you refer to, do you, specifically, not understand??

Likely duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3994963/9003

Usually this question is answered by Galois theory. The four listed intermediate fields correspond to subgroups of the Galois group $S_3$. Three subgroups are not normal, and the one of index $2$ is of course normal, i.e., $A_3$. So only $\Bbb Q(\omega)$ is normal.

Two algebraic elements $\alpha,\beta$ are conjugate if they have the same minimal polynomial. In particular, the definition of normal extension you used says that if an algebraic element $\alpha$ lies inside the extension field $L \supset F$, then all other roots of the minimal polynomial over $F$ of $\alpha$ must be also in $L$.
For your example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}w)$ is not normal because it doesn't contain $\sqrt[3]{2}$, which is also a root of $\min_{\mathbb{Q}}(\sqrt[3]{2}w) = x^3-2$. The same reason explains why  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}w^2)$ is not normal. (Here I assumed you mean $w$ is a cube root of unity).
